# add has_many through association with simple_form and cocoon not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I'am trying to create Package objects with nested attributes for Poi(Point of interest) objects using Cocoon gem. When I create a new Package I want to add existing Pois selecting them for a association. But the problem is when I create a new Package, Pois that I have added to this Package didn't linked to it. So the package_pois relations are not created when I submit the form.

There is my code:

```
class Package
  has_many :package_pois
  has_many :pois, :through => :package_pois, :class_name => 'Poi'

  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pois
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :package_pois

end


class PackagePoi
  belongs_to :poi
  belongs_to :package

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :poi, :reject_if => :all_blank

end
```

package/_form.html.erb

```
<div id="package">
<%= f.simple_fields_for :package_pois do |poi| %>
   <%= render 'package_poi_fields', :f => poi %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_association 'dd poi', f, :package_pois %>
</div>
```

package/ackage_poi_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields package-poi-fields">
    <div id="pacakge_form_list">
    <%= f.association :poi, :collection => Poi.all(:order => 'title'), :prompt => 'Add existing poi' %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove poi", f %>
</div>
```

And package-new.js:

```
$("#package a.add_fields").
      data("association-insertion-position", 'before').
      data("association-insertion-node", 'this');

    $('#package').bind('insertion-callback',
         function() {
             $(".package-poi-fields a.add_fields").
                 data("association-insertion-position", 'before').
                 data("association-insertion-node", 'this');
             $('.package-poi-fields').bind('insertion-callback',
                  function() {
                    $(this).children("#pacakge_form_list").remove();
                    $(this).children("a.add_fields").hide();
                  });
         });
```

Why it doesn't create package_pois associations? What can I ddo?
Thanks

Comment: No PackagePoi is the association class between Package and Poi, therefore it have two belongs_to

Answer (score 0):

I fixed adding :package_pois_attributes, :pois_attributes as attr_accesible